# Problem with authorization in spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

I created my Custom UserDetailService and Security Config. When I allow to enter to secure page only authorized users - OK, but if users with roles - 
HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden.
I think I do not work with roles correctly. Please, help

My UserService

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService {

}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = new User();

        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("1"));

        //There is the problem I think

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> roleList = new ArrayList<>();

        roleList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
        user.setRoleList(roleList);

        //

        user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
        user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
        user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("something")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin*").authenticated() - it works
                    //.antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("ADMIN") - it doesn't work
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

My User.class just in case

```
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
//fields
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set your user's role to `"ADMIN"`, you need to set the authority to `"ROLE_ADMIN"`.

```
roleList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

A role is the same as an authority prefixed with `"ROLE_"`.

Comment: Got this: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got 'ROLE_ADMIN' "

Comment: @hersir1 You only need to change the one line where you add the role. You do not need to change `.antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("ADMIN")`. Did you change both?

Answer (score 0):

The order should be like this:

```
.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admins/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
```

.....
.....